# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: python, docker

I have a python project that's working fine. This is its setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='project',
    version='0.4.2',
    packages=['project', 'project.models', 'project.modules', 'project.transforms'],
    url='http://12.3.4.100/team/project',
    license='',
    author='author1, author2',
    author_email='author1@company.com, athor2@company.com',
    description='Some text',
    scripts=[
        'scripts/do_something'
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'dependency1 >= 0.3.5',
        'torch >= 1.0.0',
        'dependency3 == 0.1.2',
        'numpy >= 1.15.0'
    ],
)
```

Now I'm dockerizing this project. So I've created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.5.1-cuda10.1-cudnn7-runtime

COPY project /project
COPY scripts /scripts
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --trusted-host 12.3.4.167 --extra-index-url http://12.3.4.167:8081/repository/team-python/simple

ENTRYPOINT ["scripts/do_something"]
```

But when I run the image I'm getting an error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec:
> "scripts/do_something": stat scripts/do_something: no such file or
> directory": unknown

I've been trying to google it for hours but still haven't figured out what I'm missing.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Does the file scripts/do_something exist? Is it executable? Did you try referencing it with the absolute path in ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: What does the scripts/do_something contain? Is it a python file or a bash script? Have you included the extension also or just "do_something"?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt yes it exists. It's a python file. I'm referencing it with a relative path.

Comment: @maetulj it's a python file without the .py extension.

Comment: is the host OS (from where you are running docker build) windows or linux-based?

Comment: @Alon can you try writing it this way: `ENTRYPOINT["python", "/scripts/do_something"]`?

Comment: @maetulj if I do that I get another error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'

Comment: @kerasbaz it is linux

Comment: I've been at it for more than a week, trying every possible iteration of what could not be found, what's actually wrong. This is building a GitHub actions self hosted runner via nix from scratch. its just too generic of an issue, at this point, I was thinking its best to re-compile docker with more debug lines like "what is being run when it fails", question is, why doesn't docker already print the last few lines executed when it fails? Then problems like this wouldn't exist.

Comment: in case someone else runs into this, where stat is just not giving enough information of what's being run, you can create a stat binary that calls the stat binary with strace command in front of it. This will do a system trace of everything that is being system called and run.

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential issues here. Your current issue is the disconnect between `/scripts` and `scripts/do_something` -- one assumes a full path from root, the other is a relative path. Pick one and use it in both places.

You may also have permissions issues if your docker host is windows-based instead of linux (since you aren't calling python against the file and have not chmodded it).